# How to displaying a numpy int16 array correctly with tkinter?

Tags: python, numpy, tkinter

When loading an image into tkinter, when the image is stored as a numpy array as int16, the image displayed has pixel intensity thresholds for int8, meaning that everything looks awful (all values above 255 -which are plenty- are white).  How can I set the min/max values for thresholding on tkinter?

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()

array = np.reshape(np.array(range(0,200*200), dtype='int32'),(200,200))
img =  ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.fromarray(array))

canvas = tk.Canvas(root,width=300,height=300)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_image(20,20, anchor="nw", image=img)

root.mainloop()
```

This is how the image looks like:

[image]

This does not seem to be a PIL problem, as the 'image' stored in image seems to keep the original values:

```
image=Image.fromarray(array)
image
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think the PIL supports 16 bit integer images—at least it's not on the list shown in this [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.3.x/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes).

Comment: @martineau isn't that really weird? Or am I missing something? How can one display int16 images on tkinter, without depending on PIL?

Comment: By converting them to one of the ones it does support, like 8- or 32-bit. Should be easy with numpy...although I'm no expert on using it.

Comment: int32 also displays an image with completely off threshold values. Apparently it is sticking to int8...

Comment: Modify the code in your question so it creates an `np.array` array with something in like your image for testing with please.

Comment: If it would work with that numpy array I would be good enough

Comment: Are you claiming it's supposed to look like the last image in your question? As I said, I'm no numpy expert, but I don't think so.

Comment: That last image is just the same array printed directly into the Ipython console. Why don't you think so?

Comment: Because it works for me (or at least I get what I would expect) if I change the `int32` to `int8` (which is one of the supported modes). Here's the [result](https://imgur.com/a/zSP7S1U).

Comment: You get the aliased image due to uncorrected downsampling. The original array is an increasing array from 0 to 40,000 thus the expected image is one long increasing gradient.

Comment: 40,000 max will fit in 32-bits. Convert it to that and pass the result to `Image.fromarray()` — although your eye can't distinguish that many shades of gray...so 8-bits would probably be good enough, visually at least. Ipython may very well be able to do things PIL cannot.

Comment: yup, so again, sticking to 8 bits it is...

Comment: tried that 30 minutes ago, that was my second response. It does not work. Every value over 255 appears white.

Comment: Then maybe you're not converting it properly...had to tell without seeing the code. (signing off)